# Button onclick does not execute function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/5L7etues/`button onclick="myValami()"`, doesn't seem to work.. This button should execute clearinterval inside function "myValami", but it does nothing. I went through spelling, checked it more than once. I scrolled through several questions, neither seems to fix my problem. I even tried copying the code from W3schools step-by-step https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_clearinterval but still doesnt't work. I suspect I am  missing something blatantly obvious. I appreciate any answers !

Comment: First of all, you are missing the existence of the _browser console_, in which it will _tell you_ what errors there are with your script. So you go look there now, and then you come back here and report what it had to say. (Edit the question. Plus, include relevant code _in_ the question directly. Go read [ask] please.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inline JavaScript, attach the event listener using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
var c = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0066";
ctx.fillRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
var X = 100;
var Y = 100;
var W = 50;
var H = 50;
var interval = window.setInterval(myRect, 10);

function myRect() {
  ctx.fillRect(X, Y, W, H);
  ctx.fillRect(X = X + 1, Y, W, H);

}

function myValami() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', myValami);
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas" width="400" height="200" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<button>STOP</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed:

https://jsfiddle.net/5L7etues/4/

put an id for the button (for example id="btnStop") and use the function as following:

```
btnStop.onclick = function() {
clearInterval(interval);
}
```